# ASP.Net: constant communication channel with Android clients

Tags: c#, android, wcf, communication

I am running an **ASP.Net Web Forms** application in an Azure Cloud. Now I have a special requirement that I have no idea how to solve: the server has to accept incoming connections over the internet from **Android** clients and then keep that connection open (or on standby) for a long period of time (days). **So after hours or even days, the server has to find it's way to the Android client and send some data to it.** I can use whatever technology works for both partners, but since the internet is in between, http/https is prefered as protocol (although WCF with TCP endpoints might also work when the connection is initiated by the client). The only thing I can think of is having the clients constantly poll the server if there is a command/data available, but that solution is ugly and wastes a lot of ressources. The client should react within seconds when the server has something to do for it, so I'd have to use a polling interval of ~10s. I know that http "keep alive" exists and can be utilizied in C# WebClients, but I doubt that it will work with my requirements? Is there any other possibility to achieve this?

Comment: have u ever heard of FCM downstream messaging, Use that

Comment: No I haven't yet, I will take a look at it. From a first glance it might be a valid option since I don't have to send any sensible data to the client. I wonder how they keep the connection open from the app to the Google servers...

Comment: U have to make server side implementation of FCM. I.e. use rest call and send the data to device using Instance Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Niraj's response, I found Google Firebase Cloud Messaging. After that, I read up on the XMPP protocol and the SignalR technology available for .Net and finally decided to go with SignalR as it's implementation is most simple and does not require involvement of a 3rd party.